# MySQL String search and where clause condition order

Tags: mysql, sql, string, fuzzy-search

I'm working with large number of rows in db(MySQL, innoDb engine, approx 20 milion rows) and I need to  perform fuzzy like searching quite a lot. For some reasons I decided to use jaro_winkler algorithm and for performance issues I implemented it as a function in SQL. Application is written in Python and there is a weird situation I came across today:

Comparing these two queries (called from mysql shell not via Orm or etc):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE jaro_winkler(code, '78-1747') > 0.7 AND code LIKE '%78%';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE code LIKE '%78%' AND jaro_winkler(code, '78-1747') > 0.7;
```

I noticed that first one is at least 10 times slower than the second one. It seems logical at first, but as I checked the order of conditions in WHERE should not matter.

So my question - is it the normal behaviour ?

And has someone (from practical experience) can recommend a best algorithm or function to perform fuzzy searching ? I know about damerau-levenshtein metric, but it turns to be slower than my current solution.

EDIT:
After using explain:

I created sample database really quickly and used both queries:

for the first query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE      products        ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4166    Using where
```

query time: ~ 2 seconds

explain for the second query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE      products        ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4332    Using where
```

query time: ~ 0.1 second

Comment: As pointed in this answer : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1794 you should try to use `EXPLAIN` to see if there's a difference between both queries

Comment: Order of conditions in a where clause should't matter, would be a better description of affairs. As in "This should work" is not "This will work" Explain will tell you what's going on

Comment: I put results of explain in first post.

Comment: calculates certain ratio between two provided strings

Comment: I think the problem is that jaro_winkler() is quite expensive, so the sequence of calculation matters. It would not matter, if DB could predict time it takes to assess jaro_winkler against LIKE.

Comment: I have much less experience with MySQL, but I know SQL-Server struggles to optimise queries with functions in the `WHERE` clause, I see no reason why MySQL would be different. The solution in SQL-Server is to move the function to a select in a subquery then query this in the where clause from an outer query...

Comment: ... I would imagine that if you moved the function inside a subquery the performance would remain the same. i.e. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, jaro_winkler(code, '78-1747') AS jw FROM products) p WHERE code LIKE '%78%' AND jw > 0.7;` would be the same as `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, jaro_winkler(code, '78-1747') AS jw FROM products) p WHERE jw > 0.7 AND code LIKE '%78%';`

Comment: Thanks Gareth - You were right. There were a few changes in db design and we decided not to use jaro_winkler SQL function. Instead we use nice Python package called jellyfish which deals with strin matching.